# What is the difference between the libraries libxl and libxls? (I am trying to use them in c)

Tags: c, excel, windows, function, libxl

I recently wanted to read an excel file in c using libxl. While doing some searches I came with a term libxls. What is the difference between libxl and libxls?

Comment: I am not sure, but is it related to xls and xlsx?

Comment: It's just two different libraries (unrelated to the xls(x) distinction) developed by different people - choose whichever one suits you best

Answer (score 0):

As @CherryDT says, it is two different libraries developed by different people.

libxls will read .xls files

libxl will read .xls and .xlsx files